# Changing read only struct member in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Can someone explain why this will not work? I am trying to change a read-only struct member. (Question strictly for knowledge purpose)

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b;
}A;
const A B={
    .a = 5,
    .b = 1,
};
int main()
{
    int *ptr = &B.a;
    *ptr = 12;
  
    printf("var = %d\n", B.a);
    return 0;
}
```

but this will work?

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b;
}A;

int main()
{
    const A B={
        .a = 5,
        .b = 1,
    };
    int *ptr = &B.a;
    *ptr = 12;
  
    printf("var = %d\n", B.a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Undefined behavior because you discard the `const` qualifier?

Comment: For the first one, the linker will place `B` into a read-only segment that will be enforced by the operating system. For the second one, `B` is on the stack which the operating system will place in writable memory. But this is implementation dependent. The compiler *could* decide not to put `B` on the stack for the second one, since it is supposed to be constant.

Comment: If you managed to compile either of those examples without warnings or errors, then you have not configured your compiler to give you enough error messages or you have defective compiler.

Comment: Basically, the code has undefined behavior. The best you can hope for is some plausible explanations for the observed behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Neither "will work", both versions are invalid C. Initialization in C is "as per the rules of assignment". The relevant language constraint in C17 6.5.16 goes:

> — the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type, and (considering the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion) both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types, and the type pointed to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right;

In plain English, the left operand of = is `ptr`. It is an unqualified pointer type, meaning it lacks `const`. The type to the left does not have the `const` qualifier that the type pointed to by the right `&B.a` (`const int*`) got. The above quote does not hold true.

Therefore both programs are invalid C and a compiler generating a binary executable anyway relies on undefined behavior: anything can happen and the C language doesn't specify what.